# Creating a pmf for a coin toss situation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that George starts with one dollar and will gamble with it as follows: if a fair coin toss results in heads he’ll win a dollar, and if it results in tails he’ll lose a dollar; and he’ll continue to bet a dollar on subsequent flips for up to three flips, but he’ll quit as soon as he loses the first time. Letting $X$ denote George’s net profit, give the pmf of $X$ (being sure to indicate a value for every real number).

**Attempted Solution**

Let $H,T$ denote heads and tails, respectively. Then the sample space is

${T}$, ${HT}$, ${HHT}$, ${HHH}$

These give net profits of $-1, 0, 1$, and $3$, respectively and have probabilities of $1/2, 1/4, 1/8$, and $1/8$, respectively.

Then $$p_X(x) = \begin{cases} {\frac{1}{8}} & \text{$x = 3$} \\ \frac{1}{8} & \text{$x=1$} \\ \frac{1}{4} & \text{$x=0$} \\{\frac{1}{2}} & \text{$x = -1$}\\{0} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> Did I do this correctly?

No.  Well, almost.

You have the *correct* probability masses for each outcome in the sample space.   However, the intervals in your piecewise function donut make any sense in light of the fact that the *support* should be $\{-1,0,1,3\}$, and so the *probability mass function* will have value zero at any other value of your *discrete random variable*.

Comment: I left a part out of the question that I didn't think was necessary, but maybe it is. I just edited.

Comment: But I agree with you. It doesn't make sense to have intervals. Maybe it's just for practice.

Comment: You are referring to "(being sure to indicate a value for every real number)"?  You know what the value is for every real number other than the support.  Include that.

Comment: Edited. Is that good form?

Comment: @JohnH Indeed..